# How to get a unique array value in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have array value like this snippet below:

```
a =  { [1 2 4]; [3 5 6 7]; [1 2 4]; [3 5 6 7]; [8 9]; []};
```

I am trying Matlab to get array value like this

`a =  { [1 2 4]; [3 5 6 7];[8 9]};`

Answer (score 0):

## basic solution for finding uniques

```
unique(cellfun(@(x)(mat2str(x)),a,'uniformoutput',false))
```

This can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392256/identifying-uniques-in-a-cell-array) actually.

---

## Complicating factors

Technically the empty cell at the end is also unique, perhaps you want to remove it separately like so:

```
a(cellfun(@isempty,a)) = []
```

Currently you get strings as output, this can be solved like so:

```
[~, idx] = unique(cellfun(@(x)(mat2str(x)),a,'uniformoutput',false))
a(idx)
```

I personally think that this is harder than it should be.

---

## Summary

You can get your desired output like so

```
a(cellfun(@isempty,a)) = []
[~, idx] = unique(cellfun(@(x)(mat2str(x)),a,'uniformoutput',false))
a(idx)
```