# The use of Cell array of strings in a program

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array

Suppose I have the following code

```
mc = {[2 5],[2 5],[8 9 2],[33 77 4],[102 6],[110 99],[2 5]}
```

([Identifying uniques in a cell array:Jonas Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392256/identifying-uniques-in-a-cell-array)):

```
%# convert to strings
mcs = cellfun(@(x)(mat2str(x)),mc,'uniformoutput',false);

%# run unique
[uniqueCells,idxOfUnique,idxYouWant] = unique(mcs);

fileName = ['C:\Users\MATLAB\matrice_Result.mat'];  
save(fileName,'uniqueCells');
```

to load the result and use it as a cell, **Can I do that ?**:

```
load('C:\Users\MATLAB\matrice_Result.mat');
A = uniqueCells;

B = [5 77 41 66 7];
```

(Finding the vectors of the cell A that contain at least one element of the vector B: [Divakar Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152718/how-to-find-the-vectors-of-the-cell-a-that-contain-at-least-one-element-of-the-v))

```
R = A(arrayfun(@(n) any(ismember(B,A{n})),1:numel(A)));
```

I have the impression that the second code does not recognize A !!!

Comment: Well, `B` is numbers, `A{n}` is strings. Of course `ismember` will all `false`

Comment: @LuisMendo: I know, but I'm ashamed to say that I can not solve this problem!

Comment: Oh I see. Wait a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `str2num(A{n})` to convert each cell of `A` back into numeric form:

```
R = A(arrayfun(@(n) any(ismember(B,str2num(A{n}))),1:numel(A)));
```

The above gives the result in string form, because `A{n}` is converted to numbers within `ismember` but `A` is left in string form. If you want the result in numeric form, first convert `A` and then apply your (Divakar's) original line to the converted `A`:

```
A_num = cellfun(@str2num, A, 'uniformoutput', 0);
R = A_num(arrayfun(@(n) any(ismember(B,A_num{n})),1:numel(A)));
```